# How to check the user is registered in ejabberd server or not using asmack

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

The following is the code that I used to search the given user registered in xmpp server or not using asmack.

```
        UserSearchManager userSearchManager = new UserSearchManager(
                connection);
        Form searchForm;
        try {
            searchForm = userSearchManager.getSearchForm("vjud."
                    + connection.getServiceName());

        Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
        answerForm.setAnswer("user", true);
        answerForm.setAnswer("search", "test"); // here i'm passsing the
                                                // Text value to search

        ReportedData resultData;
        resultData = userSearchManager.getSearchResults(answerForm,
                "vjud." + connection.getServiceName());

        Iterator<Row> it = resultData.getRows();
        Row row = null;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String value = it.next().toString();
            Log.i("Iteartor values......", " " + value);
            System.out.println("Jabber_id :"
                    + row.getValues("jid").next().toString());
            System.out.println("Name :"
                    + row.getValues("Name").next().toString());
            row = it.next();
        }

        } catch (XMPPException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm(); getting NullPointerException.Anyone please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Jabber User Directory to know if a user is registered or not. Jabber User Directory (vjud) is based on the info user publish in their Vcard. A registered user that do not have a Vcard will not be matched by the search.